# I am trying to setup up NFS with two NFS clients and one NFS server

Tags: networking, server, permissions, mount, nfs

I am trying to setup NFS with two nfs clients and one nfs server. I have created a shared directory called repo.

I want this directory to have the user:group to be elasticsearch:elasticsearch.

But when I am changing the user:group to elasticsearch on server the user and group on client machine are changing to some other user and group.

Executed chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch repo on server
server -> drwxr-xr-x   2   elasticsearch   elasticsearch   4096 Jun 16 09:54 repo

on client machine which is now part of NFS got change to:
client -> drwxr-xr-x   2    _rpc   xrdp     4096  Jun 16 04:24 repo

I tried using no_root_squash also.

I don't want user and group to be changed

The OS which I am using is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details for server and/or clients.  You've also not said where you executed the your change of ownership (*and whether or not the server/clients match with regards user/groups*)

Comment: As @guiverc hints towards: What matters are UID and GID (the numbers), not the names that you see. A group with GID 1036 might be "elasticsearch" on your server, but "alex" on your client. Please provide the UID and GID for the user on the server and the client. Also, what is it that you want to achieve? That the names look the same? Or read/write access? Persistent ownership of files?